# PM2 can not reload application

Tags: node.js, pm2

My application is working very well. I`m using PM2 clustering mode in this application and I reloaded it to much without any error. But now when I wanna reload my app, it does not work and shows me this error :

[image]

This is my reloading command:

```
pm2 reload myapp
```

Comment: Try restart instead of reload

Comment: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2951

Comment: @ArminŠupuk I wanna deploy my app without restarting !! because of that I`m using "reload". You still suggest using "restart"

Comment: Yes, but you got an error, so try to restart it

Comment: I found the solution. "pm2 reload myapp --force"